# Can the Armorer Artificer's Infiltrator Lightning Launcher be used if set into a full hand?

Tags: dnd-5e, artificer

Per RAW, if the Lightning Launcher of the Infiltrator version of Arcane Armor is put onto one of the fists, can it be used to make an attack if that hand is full, either due to wielding a weapon/shield or just holding onto an object?

The description doesn't seem to prohibit this, though it seems intuitive that it would be an issue. But the beam could originate from the back of the hand or knuckles, so I don't see RAW why my player couldn't do this.

Any insight on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Nothing says you need a free hand.

There are several reasons to think the lightning launcher does *not* require a free hand. The first is what you mentioned; a lightning launcher doesn't even have to be mounted on your hands:

> **Lightning Launcher.** A gemlike node appears on one of your armored fists *or on the chest* (your choice).

It seems obvious that a chest-mounted weapon doesn't require a free hand to fire, and even if it's mounted on a hand, it doesn't say it's in your palm like Iron Man's repulsors. As you said, it very well may be a gem on the back of the hand and fully usable while you're holding something else.

### The exception proves the rule.

But the better reason to think there's no intent that you need a free hand is by comparison with the alternative. The Guardian-class armor has a different weapon:

> **Thunder Gauntlets.** Each of the armor's gauntlets counts as a simple melee weapon *while you aren't holding anything in it*...

Since the thunder gauntlets specifically require you to have your hands empty to use them, and the lightning launcher makes no such claim, clearly there's no intent that the lightning launcher requires a free hand. They would have said so if they meant for such a requirement to exist.

Comment: Giving the tick to this answer for including a reference to a comparable weapon/feature for contrast.

Answer (score 7):

### RAW is vague but leans towards it not being a problem

> **Lightning Launcher.** A gemlike node appears on one of your armored fists or on the chest (your choice). It counts as a simple ranged weapon, with a normal range of 90 feet and a long range of 300 feet, and it deals 1d6 lightning damage on a hit. Once on each of your turns when you hit a creature with it, you can deal an extra 1d6 lightning damage to that target.

It says "*on* your fist," not "in your hand," where a weapon might be. Though personally, I think the more compelling argument is that you can have it mounted on a different body part entirely, which communicates to me that there's no reason for it to functionally occupy your hand even if it's located there.